# Generate random integer from discrete selection?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to generate random numbers but *only* certain numbers. I know to generate a random number between 0 and 10 you'd use:

```
arc4random_uniform(11)
```

But what if I wanted to generate a random number between a selection of, say 3, 5, 8, and 10?

Comment: `[3, 5, 8, 10][Int(arc4random_uniform(4))]`

Comment: between 0 and 10 you'd use: arc4random_uniform(9) it is wrong. You would need to use  arc4random_uniform(11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vacawama is right and should be given credit.

a little more thought.

Chose what number you want and put them into an array. then use the index of the array to get the

[3, 5, 8, 10]

array index starts at zero so; [0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 8, 3: 10].

using "4" within the arc4random will let you choose between 0-3.

Comment: Oh yes, so much simpler than I was thinking. Thank you